# Как сделать ширину inline элемента точно по ширине контента

Tags: css

Вот пример задачи:

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
}
.content {
  border: 1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">

  <span class="content">
    Hello!!! Hello!!! Hello!!! Hello!!! Hello!!! Hello!!! Hello!!! Hello!!! Hello!!! Hello!!! Hello!!! Hello!!! Hello!!!
    </span>

  <div>
    @@@
  </div>
</div>
```

здесь "@@@" не прилегает к тексту, ширина дива 'content' больше, чем хотелось бы. word-break: break-all - не подходит по условию задачи.

Comment: Я тут впервые, извините за криво вставленную ссылку.

Comment: код нужно вставлять **непосредственно** в вопрос, об этом, кстати, должна была быть подсказка при попытке вставить ссылку на jsfiddle

Comment: что-то я не вижу `inline` элементов, как только контейнеру присвоили `display:flex` дочерние перестали быть `inline` или `block`, хотя не, хром, например показывает, что теперь все имеют `display:block`

Comment: Вам надо, чтобы Hello!!! Hello! поместились в одну строку? Непонятно просто

Comment: вообще говоря, в данном случае элемент как раз и расширился по ширине контента

Comment: @Grundy, про вставку кода понял, спасибо.

Comment: Grundy, Василий, я постарался более понятно пояснить смысл задачи в комментарии к ответу ниже.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

В вашем примере используется `flexbox` и при этом вы спрашиваете про `inline` элемент внутри него, что наводит на мысль, что вы не совсем понимаете работу вашей верстки в целом. Поэтому ответ ниже может только добавить путаницу, тк верен только `flexbox` верстки.

Левому блоку необходимо запретить расширяться и позволить сужаться, и выставить базовую ширину в ноль. Правому наоборот разрешить расширяться и запретить сужаться, и выставить автоматическую ширину - тоесть занимать изначально максимально доступную ширину.

```
flex: 0 1 0;
```

Расшифровывается как:

```
flex-grow: 0;
flex-shrink: 1;
flex-basis: 0;
```

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
}

.content {
  border: 1px solid orange;
  flex: 0 1 0;
}

.parent > div {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">

  <span class="content">
    Hello!!! Hello!!! Hello!!! Hello!!! Hello!!! Hello!!! Hello!!! Hello!!! Hello!!! Hello!!! Hello!!! Hello!!! Hello!!!
  </span>

  <div>
    @@@
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за замечания, буду исправляться :) Но использовать flex не обязательно, можно использовать всё, кроме js. Я плохо объяснил смысл задачи. Нужно, чтобы левый блок расширялся по контенту, а правый всегда прилегал к нему абсолютно плотно и никогда не переносился бы на нижнюю строку. Вся проблема в той ситуации, когда сожержимое левого блока состоит из слов, которые как видно из примера, такой ширины, что 3 не вмещаются в строку, а 2 вмещаются, при этом образуется пространство справа, вопрос в том можно ли его как-то убрать. Т.е. чтобы оранжевая рамка всегда плотно прилегала к контенту.

Answer (score 1):

Оно итак на всю доступную ширину растянет блок контента. У вас стоит в

```
.parent {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 200px; //вот макс длина
  display: flex;
}
```

максимальная ширина 200px. измените на `width: 100%;`и возможно стоит поставить `display: inline-flex;`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я постарался пояснить условия задачи более понятно в комментарии к ответу @mJeevas. Первый раз задавал тут вопрос и получилось жутко каряво, простите.